# Submenu are not displayed due to frameset

Tags: html, css

I am facing a issue in my project where i want to display the menu and submenu.But the submenu is not getting displayed due to rows set in the frameset.
So you help me what change has to done so that the marque.html runs in the background and submenu and submenu's-->menu are displayed correctly.

Below is the code snippet:

```css
ul#css3menu1, ul#css3menu1 ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #dedede;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #5f5f5f;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

ul#css3menu1 ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  -moz-box-shadow: 3.5px 3.5px 5px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3.5px 3.5px 5px #000000;
  box-shadow: 3.5px 3.5px 5px #000000;
  background-color: #0000ff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-color: #d4d4d4;
  padding: 0 10px 10px;
}

ul#css3menu1 li:hover > * {
  display: block;
}

ul#css3menu1 li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
  float: left;
}

ul#css3menu1 li:hover {
  z-index: 1;
}

ul#css3menu1 ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

ul#css3menu1 {
  font-size: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  padding: 0;
  *display: inline;
}

* html ul#css3menu1 li a {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul#css3menu1 > li {
  margin: 0;
}

ul#css3menu1 a:active, ul#css3menu1 a:focus {
  outline-style: none;
}

ul#css3menu1 a {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: bold 14px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: #0000ff;
  text-shadow: #FFF 0 0 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 9px 10px 9px 10px;
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
  background-image: url("mainbk.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  border-width: 0 0 0 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #C0C0C0;
}

ul#css3menu1 ul li {
  float: none;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}

ul#css3menu1 ul a {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #0000ff;
  background-image: none;
  border-width: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  font: 14px Tahoma;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul#css3menu1 li:hover > a, ul#css3menu1 li a.pressed {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #C0C0C0;
  border-style: solid;
  color: #0000ff;
  text-shadow: #FFF 0 0 1px;
  background-image: url("mainbk.png");
  background-position: 0 100px;
}

ul#css3menu1 span {
  display: block;
  overflow: visible;
  background-position: right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

ul#css3menu1 ul span {
  background-image: url("arrowsub.png");
  padding-right: 12px;
}

ul#css3menu1 > li.switch {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 25px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 9px 10px 9px 10px;
}

ul#css3menu1 > li.switch:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #0000ff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px #0000ff, 0 16px #0000ff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px #0000ff, 0 16px #0000ff;
  box-shadow: 0 8px #0000ff, 0 16px #0000ff;
}

ul#css3menu1 > li.switch:hover:before {
  background: #0000ff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px #0000ff, 0 16px #0000ff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px #0000ff, 0 16px #0000ff;
  box-shadow: 0 8px #0000ff, 0 16px #0000ff;
}

.c3m-switch-input {
  display: none;
}

ul#css3menu1 li:hover > a, ul#css3menu1 li > a.pressed {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: url("mainbk.png");
  background-position: 0 100px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #C0C0C0;
  color: #0000ff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: #FFF 0 0 1px;
}

ul#css3menu1 ul li:hover > a, ul#css3menu1 ul li > a.pressed {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-image: none;
  color: #FF0DDB;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul#css3menu1 li.toplast > a {
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  ul#css3menu1 > li {
    position: initial;
  }

  ul#css3menu1 ul .submenu, ul#css3menu1 li > ul {
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
    top: 100%;
  }

  ul#css3menu1 .submenu, ul#css3menu1 ul, ul#css3menu1 .column {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-right: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 118px) {
  ul#css3menu1 {
    width: 100%;
  }

  ul#css3menu1 > li {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 100% !important;
  }

  ul#css3menu1 > li.switch, .c3m-switch-input:checked + ul#css3menu1 > li + li {
    display: block;
  }

  ul#css3menu1 > li.switch > label {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>css3menu.com</title>
  <!-- Start css3menu.com HEAD section -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="check_files/css3menu1/style.css" type="text/css" /><style type="text/css">._css3m{display:none}</style>
  <!-- End css3menu.com HEAD section -->


</head>
<body ontouchstart="" style="background-color:#EBEBEB">
<!-- Start css3menu.com BODY section -->
<input type="checkbox" id="css3menu-switcher" class="c3m-switch-input">
<ul id="css3menu1" class="topmenu">
  <li class="switch"><label onclick="" for="css3menu-switcher"></label></li>
  <li class="toplast"><a href="#" target="_parent" style="width:110px;height:17px;line-height:17px;"><span>Administrator</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Administrator 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Administrator 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Administrator 1</span></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Administrator 1 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Administrator 1 0</a></li>
        </ul></li>
      <li><a href="#">Administrator 0</a></li>
    </ul></li>
</ul><p class="_css3m"><a href="http://css3menu.com/">css menu</a> by Css3Menu.com</p>
<!-- End css3menu.com BODY section -->

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<marquee>Welcome to test screen</marquee>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<frameset border="0" framespacing="0" rows=98,1* frameborder="no" cols=*>
  <frame name=topnav marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="banner.html" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no">

  <frameset border="0" framespacing="0" rows=25,1* frameborder="no" cols=*>
    <frame name=topnav marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="MenuBar.html" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no">

    <frameset border="0" framespacing="0" rows=20,1* frameborder="no" cols=*>
      <frame name=topnav marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="marque.html" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no">

    </frameset>
  </frameset>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Any Suggestion will help me alot.
Thanks in advance

Comment: 1st of all: forget about this frame nonsense ... 2nd: get a designer cuz that looks ugly as hell ... 3rd: don't try to reinvent the wheel .. there are thousands of redy-to-use css menus out there, just google it

Comment: Hi Fabian I am very new to html and css so i was not much aware and just got this css using the tool.I saw your edited version and when i tried the edited version it too did not work.Still i am not getting submenu's.Can  you tell what more code change is required it will be very helpful?